# PHP/CURL freezing server

Tags: php, ajax, curl, php-curl

I have php CURL code with runs through an ajax script. The code works well, no issues, but I have noticed, that when the code is executed, the whole server stops/freezes until the CURL is complete. This is just happening during testing faze. My server would be in a complete time out if this was a live site.

Running Apache2, PHP7.4, php7.4-curl, Debian 10

```
$url_sh = "****";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_sh);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);
$approved_img = '<img src="'.$obj['lighthouseResult']['audits']['final-screenshot']['details']['data'].'">';
```

Comment: If the page containing this code has an open session, then subsequent requests will block until the session is closed either explicitly, or when the code exits. It is only blocked for _that user/session_, not the entire server.

Comment: Show us a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: "*the whole server stops/freezes*" - what does this mean, exactly?  What have you observed, and how?

Comment: Thanks  @Sammitch that seams to be the case

Answer (score 0):

As per @Sammitch :

> If the page containing this code has an open session, then subsequent
> requests will block until the session is closed either explicitly, or
> when the code exits. It is only blocked for that user/session, not the
> entire server.

Comment: You can call [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close) before a long-running operation to free up the session lock for another process.